VertexAI - How to prevent model users from changing its objective?
I have an assistant built on Vertex AI using Gemini Pro that has a certain defined Objective (say Objective A). Once the objective has been well established for the model using a meticulously designed set of prompts, and we have verified that the results from the model are satisfactory, we are opening it up for beta testing.
Our consumers will primarily interact with the system through a chat interface, through the typical question / answers flow between users and our model. However, this design seems to have a flaw in the design.
It seems the users are able to use prompting techniques to alter the objective of the model ( to say Objective B ).
What we would like to achieve is:

complete segregation of knowledge between 2 user "sessions". Much like what OpenAI provides as a "thread" of messages.
prevent our users from re-training our models or polluting it with data.
re-use the context of the user's interaction with other "assistants". Our ultimate goal would be to have multiple assistants serving different purposes to the user, while a central context of the user is created ( back to OpenAI example, this would be achieved using Assistants and Threads )

Would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this with Vertex AI, preferably using Gemini models.
FYI, our primary motivation for not choosing to build on OpenAI was financial cost, and the need for recent data from the internet ( gemini models seem to have more recent info than chatgpt does ).
